# Unexpected token < when using Angular Translate

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, internationalization, angular-translate

I am still learning more about angularjs. I've been following the instructions of this video **[angular-translate tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewTS5pJ_4cU)** but when I want to test the code I get the error in chrome: **Unexpected token <**

> angular-translate.min.js:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>
> angular-sanitize.min.js:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Also with this error:

> jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=testdemo&p1=Error…host%3A8080%2FTestDemo%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A390)

Chrome points to the first tag found on my html (5th line = doctype) as the error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Basically I have my app.js for the app module

```
var app = angular.module('TestDemo', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'pascalprecht.translate', 'ngSanitize']);
```

I have another js as translations.js

```
app.config(function($translateProvider){
    $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('en');
    $translateProvider.registerAvailableLanguageKeys(['en', 'es'], {
        'en_*': 'en',
        'es_*': 'es'
    });

    $translateProvider.translations('en', {
        "WELCOME": "Welcome"
    });

    $translateProvider.translations('es', {
        "WELCOME": "Bienvenido"
    });

    $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escape');
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
});
```

This is my page index.html

```
<body ng-controller="TestController">
    <h1>{{ 'WELCOME' | translate }}</h1>

    <script src="../jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../angular-translate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="../bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../app.js"></script>
    <script src="../routing.js"></script>
    <script src="../translations.js"></script>  
    <script src="../services.js"></script>
    <script src="../controllers.js"></script>
</body>
```

My controller

```
app.controller('TestController', function($scope, $translate, TestService) {
    $translate.use('en');
});
```

So why do I get the unexpected token error?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I downloaded the files for angular-translate and angular-sanitize incorrectly. So I downloaded again these files and worked well.

Comment: A simple way of causing this error is misspelling an href / src. Say Chrome tries to load a script, but due to the typo the server sends a 404 page. So instead of JS code, Chrome gets HTML, starting with a `<`.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I tried to check the scripts tags but I don't see any error as I provided the code. I worked before until I added the tags for translate and sanitize and the new translations.js